# iCloud Photo Sharing

Tags: icloud

I have a Macbook Air and an iPhone 6 and iCloud Photo Sharing is turned on.  Both are giving me messages that there's no more room for photos. I have around 3,000 photos. I thought my photos were stored in iCloud and not on my devices.  How can I remove photos from my Mac and my phone without deleting them from my iCloud?  And how do I access my iCloud photos?

Answer (score 1):

Kay -

**All of your photos, if you have iCloud Photo Library turned on, are automatically uploaded to iCloud.**

All photos you upload to iCloud are available to be accessed online from the **[iCloud website](http://www.icloud.com)**. Simply sign in and select **Photos.** They are also automatically on your devices.

#### Now for removing them from your Mac:

1. Open Photos and press `command + ,` to open the preference pane.
2. Select iCloud at the top and press Optimize Mac Storage *This button only appears if iCloud Photo Library is checked above.*
   [image: Photos screenshot]

#### BONUS: Removing photos from the iPhone

1. Open `Settings -> Photos & Camera`
2. Select Optimize iPhone Storage under the iCloud Photo Library switch. *This button only appears if iCloud Photo Library is enabled.*

[image]